# ASP.NET Core 3.1 : Shared Localization not working for version 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I may be not doing the correct configurations in the `Startup.cs` file. I have created a demo application to make it working, but after trying various things it is not working. The demo repository is available at following link

https://github.com/gurpreet42/MyAppV3

Configurations of startup.cs files are

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<LocService>();
   services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

   services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                                            {
                                                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                                new CultureInfo("nl")
                                            };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

   services.AddMvc()
           .AddViewLocalization()
           .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                {
                   options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                   {
                       var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                       return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                   };
               }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                        IHostingEnvironment env,
                        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Localisation
    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
}
```

The code in the `LocService` class is

```
public class LocService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
    {
        var value= _localizer[key];
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now on our controller, we can access the localized string as

```
localizerService.GetLocalizedHtmlString("my_string")
```

Under the "Resources" folder we have following files present

```
SharedResource.cs
SharedResource.en-US.resx
SharedResource.nl.resx
```

Please suggest where the configurations are wrong or do I need to add some extra package?

Comment: Did you solve your issue I have the same issue its not finding the resource file in a .net core 3.1 dll

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that in asp.net core 3.1, you need to place `SharedResource.cs` out of `Resources` folder(see this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17733))

If class `SharedResource.cs` and `SharedResource.*.resx` in same folder, the namespace will be error in compiled dll `xxx.lang.dll`.

So, just delete original `SharedResource.cs` create a new one under the project directly:

```
namespace MyAppV3
{
    public class SharedResource
    {
    }
}
```

And read resource files to the `Resources` folder.

Comment: Thanks @XingZou, It is really a break in asp.net 3.1
After moving the SharedResouce.cs file outside the 'Resource' folder (on root of the project) It worked.

Comment: I had the same problem, solution worked, but why did they change this? I liked to have the resource files collapse under the class, and now we got an extra file in the root, :facepalm:

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to create the LocService you can use IStringLocalizer.

"Resources" folder structure

```
SharedResource.cs
SharedResource.en-US.resx
SharedResource.nl.resx
```

At the class SharedResource, do not add "Resources" in the namespace. Like MyAppV3.Resources. Please keep it just MyAppV3.

```
namespace MyAppV3
{
    public class SharedResource
    {
    }
}
```

Add in your .csproj the following property

```
<PropertyGroup><EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>false</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention></PropertyGroup>
```

Add to startup.cs > ConfigureServices

```
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();

    services
        .Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var cultures = new[]
                                   {
                                       new CultureInfo("en"),
                                       new CultureInfo("nl")
                                   };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
            });
```

Startup.cs > Configure

```
   app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices
            .GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
```

Add to the controller the IStringLocalizer parameter.

```
   public MyTestController(IStringLocalizer localizer)
   {
        this.localizer = localizer;
   }

   public IActionResult Get()
   {          
        var value = this.localizer.GetString("RessourceName");
        return this.Ok(value);
   }
```

Comment: During my upgrade from 2.2 to 3.1, I had an issue where SharedResources was working fine, but IViewLocalizer was not. I tried number of different things, but `<PropertyGroup><EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>false</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention></PropertyGroup>` was the only thing I ended up changing to get it to work. So what this does it reverts the behavior to how it worked in 2.2. Now, that I have a solution, I will explore how to fix this properly. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link about, [Resource manifest file name change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/msbuild).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue during upgrade from 2.2 to 3.1.

In 2.2 my setup was:

```
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
               ... <omitted for brevity>
            })
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

All resources where in "Resources" folder. SharedResources.cs had recommended namespace of the project:

```
// *************************
// DO NOT CHANGE NAMESPACE
// *************************
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace MyProject
{
    // Dummy class to group shared resources
    public class SharedResources
    {
    }
}
```

And View Localizations were based on the path e.g.

```
Resources
   Pages
      Error.en-US.resx
      Error.ja-JP.resx
```

With 3.1, recommended setup was (with minimal changes):

```
        services.AddLocalization();
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllersWithViews(config =>
            {
               ... <omitted for brevity>
            })
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

At this point SharedResources was working fine but IViewLocalizer and view localizations were not working.

I found two ways to fix it based on above suggestions and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/msbuild):

1. Opt out of the new naming convention, effectively going back to what was used in 2.2 by adding following to csproj file:

   ```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>false</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
    </PropertyGroup>
   ```

And, adding `options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"` back to `services.AddLocalization()`.

2. Keep 3.1 setup and fix each view localization by adding dummy `.cs` file with namespace that is outside of resources folder, for example:

   ```
   Resources
      Pages
         Error.cs
         Error.en-US.resx
         Error.ja-JP.resx
   ```

Where `Error.cs` is:

```
// *************************
// DO NOT CHANGE NAMESPACE
// *************************
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace MyProject.Pages
{
    // Dummy class to group shared resources
    public class Error
    {
    }
}
```

So if you have lots of View Localizations like me, #1 option would probably be better, as it is configuration change only, leaving all existing view localization as they were.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the namespace in my case. Modifying it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with Localization over the past week, and came across a much simpler solution that I have not yet seen a downside for, and I can't figure out why almost nobody does it this way.

1. Create a resource file without a culture (e.g. Resource.resx) for your default strings, and one (or multiple) with a culture (e.g. Resource.nl.resx).
2. Then on the Resource file set Access Modifier to 'Public':
   [image where to set access modifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEh3g.png)

3. In your views and controllers you can then just use:

   @Resource.CurrentMarketValue

like in the good old days! As long as you are 'using *project*.Resources'.

No magic strings, IntelliSense, and language switching still works fine. Don't even need to change Startup.cs.

You can set the culture as follows:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
```